# VBA copy row values one row up

Tags: excel, vba

I have a filtered spreadsheet with alternating rows as follows:
- a value in col A in one row
- next row has values in col C and E
Using VBA, how do I copy paste the values in col C and E up one row for the entire used range of the sheet?

[image]

I want the numbers to be moved up one row to be in the same row as the letters.

Comment: Please include the code you are using in your question and explain the problems you are having with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
Sub MoveValues()    
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each Row In .Rows
            If Row.Cells(3) <> 0 Then
                Range(Cells(Row.Row, 3), Cells(Row.Row, 5)).Cut Destination:=Range(Cells(Row.Row - 1, 3), Cells(Row.Row - 1, 5))
            End If
        Next Row
    End With
End Sub
```